# What is the cleanest / efficient way to reference a child GameObject? Via grabbing or just searching by name / tag?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been thinking about which would be the best, cleaner and efficient way to reference a child of my object in my script. I mean, I have a GameObject named Player, and it have a gun. I know that he will always hold up it and I need have it in a variable to do some things. I have something like:

myGun.shoot();

And I have 2 ways to get myGun object.

1st: by making public myGun and grab it to the script.
2nd: by searching the reference with findObjectWithTag or similars.

Which one is the best way to do it and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For regular components

As for me, best practice in this case it creating field with link. Why?

1. If you will use tags - at some point there are many of tags will be created and easy to make bug while managing it
2. If you will use find by name - after some point you catch huge problems with updating your hierarchy. For example, in future you will remove/rename child - you newer know when exactly script will throw null reference exception.
3. If you use fields - you always know when and how each child uses. Also this very good practice when you work in team - you don't need to describe team members how to interact with your code.
4. If you use fields - you can make clear controller with hidden fields to avoid children editing straight bypassing the controller (hide links to children via using of `[SerializeField]`).

### For small components

For small components also good practice finding by component. For example, if you have UI timer constructed with 1 text label and 2-3 GameObjects - there are more easier to find text field via `gameobject.GetComponentInChild<Text>();`.

### For dynamically created components

In this case better way to create field with link to root object and in runtime manage links to dynamically created children.
For example, create

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _leftWeaponRoot;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _rigthtWeaponRoot;
```

and add weapons as children in runtime.

Comment: good answer, I'll just add that in our game players have dynamic weapons, so when we create the player we instantiate the object, place it under the "weapon holder" transform in the correct hand bone, and store the reference in the class. (here is where using `SerializedFieldAttribute` comes into play)